# ssrs dril through to another report from matrix collapsed mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created a matrix report table with the option to drill down in that matrix with the + sign in both columns and rows.
The user can also click on any text-box in the matrix and it actions to a different report with parameters to view details.
[image]

Both tables are 1 report and 1 matrix table in different settings of hide/show  groups.

In the right table I sent the number marked red is an example for drill through with parameters  sales+mary, and aria1+product 2.
On the left, the drill through always sends with sales-david as parameter because he was first.
How can I drill-through with a parameter that represents the entire group of sales?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use InScope("SalesPerson") or simialr to test the scope of the cell you click on. If it's inscope of the detail column group you can pass the actual SalesPerson to the drill down report, if not then pass some arbitrary value (say -1) and have you sub-report ignore SalesPerson if the parameter is -1

InScope("SalesPerson") will return true if the group is expanded or false if it's not.

You can read about InScope here 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156490(v=sql.100).aspx